# How to put ScrollView into Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a XML file with TabHost but I have problems to put ScrollView into each tab. The XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buscar eventos:"  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/thTabH"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="317dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >                    
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:text="Nombre:"
                                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"                             android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>     

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="Provincia:" 
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText02" 
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="Localidad:" 
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText02" 
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="Fecha:" 
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <Button android:id="@+id/selecionarFecha"  android:text="Seleccionar"
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <Button android:id="@+id/realizarBusqueda"  android:text="Buscar eventos"
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" />    

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="Distancia desde aquí (km):" 
                            android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spOpcion1"
                            android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="50dp" 
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:text="Fecha:" 
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <Button android:id="@+id/selecionarFecha"  android:text="Seleccionar"
                                android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>                             
                        <TextView  android:text="" android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"/>
                        <Button android:id="@+id/realizarBusqueda"  android:text="Buscar eventos"
                            android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" />    

                    </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>  
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to have a ScrollView in each tab (inside). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each one of your two `LinearLayout` tabs with a `ScrollView` and change the height of your LinearLayouts to `wrap_content`.

Comment: I've tried it. But I obtain this error: `Exception raised during rendering: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id -1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log`  With: `<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > `

Comment: You should also update your ids. Remove `@+id/tab1` from your `LinearLayout` and use it for the `ScrollView`. Do the same thing for the second tab too.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating layout in the `TabHost` itself.

Just write a TabHost layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabhost_linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And, at run time you can set the number of tabs that your TabActivity will host. Adding different layout on each tab. And so you can set scrollview for each layout that will be displayed.

Comment: But I need to have a static TexView before TabHost. For this I've put a LinearLayout also.